# how to open a page and force an iframe load?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I would like to know is it possible to, when clicking a link, open a main page and force to load another page in a frame inside the main page?

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the following `js` script on the `main page` and you are done

```
function loadframe(){
  var i = document.getElementById("iframeID");
  i.src = "path/to/file";
};

// Check for browser support of event handling capability
if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", loadIframe, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", loadIframe);
else window.onload = loadIframe;
```

Comment: @LucasMatos, thats completely different from what was asked before. Please revert to the original question and ask a new one for current update.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open popup using window.open ("new_url.php", "mywindow","status=1,toolbar=1");

and In new_url.php you can set iframe...